# Not able to reconstruct RGB565 image from raw data using QImage

Tags: qt, file, rgb, qimage

I am trying to reconstruct an image from a file which is in Intel hex 386 format. After parsing the file all the data I am copying to a `QByteArray` and same array is used to create a `QImage` Object. But whatever image is which I got after reconstructing is not perfect. I am getting blue color instead of black, edges are not clear etc. The text file which I am parsing is a ram memory dump from STM32F4 controller (arm).The image is stored in RGB565 format.

Code to create the image:

```
{
    QString strFilename;
    Hex386Parser oFileParser;
    strFilename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Select a file", QDir::homePath());
    oFileParser.parseFile(strFilename, oByteArray);
    QImage image(320, 240, QImage::Format_RGB16);

    for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); y++)
    {
        memcpy(image.scanLine(y), oByteArray.constData() + y * image.bytesPerLine(),
            image.bytesPerLine());
    }

    qDebug() <<"Size of the byte array is " <<oByteArray.size();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    label->show();
}
```

Code to used to parse the file:

```
#define QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII
void Hex386Parser::parseFile(QString strFilename,QByteArray& ref_ByteArray)
{
    QFile oFile(strFilename);
    std::stringstream sstr;
    QString strLength;

    int unLength = 0, unAddress = 0,unDescriptor =0xFFFF,nIndex =0,nlineno=0;
    if (oFile.open((QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)))
    {
        QTextStream in(&oFile);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            nIndex = 0;
            nlineno++;
            //unsigned char *pCharFrame = (unsigned char *)line.toStdString().c_str();
            if (':' != line.at(nIndex))
            {
                // file corrupted
                return;
            }
            nIndex++;

            {
                strLength = line.mid(nIndex, 2);
                sstr << strLength.toStdString();
                sstr << std::hex;
                sstr >> unLength; // get length of the record
                strLength.clear();
                sstr.clear();
            }

            nIndex += 2;
            unAddress = line.mid(nIndex,4).toInt(); //  get address bytes
            nIndex +=4;
            unDescriptor = line.mid(nIndex, 2).toInt(); // get data descriptor
            nIndex += 2;
            switch(unDescriptor)
            {
            case data_record:
                ref_ByteArray.append((line.mid(nIndex, unLength )));
                // add data to bytearray
                break;
            case end_of_file_record:
                break;
            case extended_segment_address_record:
                break;
            case extended_linear_address_record:
                break;
            case start_linear_address_record:
                break;
            }
        }
        oFile.close();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line` contains hex string data representations where each byte is coded as two characters.

You want binary bytes. So, `2 * unLength` symbols should be read from `line`. Then, that data string should converted to binary, for example:

```
{
case data_record:
    QByteArray hex = line.mid(nIndex, 2 * unLength ).toLatin1();
    QByteArray binary = QByteArray::fromHex(hex);
    ref_ByteArray.append(binary);
...
}
```